# How do I get Bluetooth to work on Ubuntu 19.10 with an ASUS PCE-AC55BT PCI-E card?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I recently installed a PCI-E card that gives me both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth. Previously I was using Bluetooth through a USB connected to one of the USB ports.

I am dual-booting both Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

My Wi-Fi is working fine on Ubuntu.
Both my Wi-Fi and Bluetooth are working fine on Windows 7.

**OS: Ubuntu 19.10
Kernel: Linux 5.3.0-40-generic**

I've run the following commands that I found online, and it indicates that Bluetooth is detected on the system at least (somewhat)

```
sudo rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. M4A785/P7P55 Motherboard [1043:83a3]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
--
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 [8086:0010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04d9:a0d0 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.165818] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.323556] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    3.020355] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.77d01142.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.110744] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.268042] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.268057] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.268060] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.268062] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.268064] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.297979] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.297980] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.297984] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.393306] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[    5.393330] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
```

When I go into Bluetooth settings and turn on Bluetooth, nothing happens, it just says 'Turn on to connect devices and receive file transfers', whereas previously devices would enumerate or it would instantly connect to my headphones.

What has gone wrong?

Comment: This is now resolved. I have no idea why this would work, but I took a suggestion from elsewhere on the web that stated to do a complete cold boot.

So I turned off the computer, turned off the power supply, and then attempted to start the computer (to get rid of any residual charge). Then powered on the power supply and started as normal. Booted into Ubuntu and voilà -- it worked. If anyone knows why this could be, please let me know. Wondering if a plain old restart kept some power to the RAM within the PCI-E card and hence it couldn't refresh properly.